# Sketch and express a double integral of an arbitrary function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

If $f$ is an arbitrary and continuous function in $R$, sketch $R$ and express the following double integral:

$$\iint_Rf(x,y) \, dA$$

And $R$ being the region limited by the graph of the following equations:

$-x+y^2=0$, $-3x+y^2+18=0$ and $y \geq 0$

I found the integral:
$$\int_0^3\int_{y^2}^{\frac{y^2+18}{3}}1 \, dx \, dy$$

And the sketch of $R$:
[image: Sketch of R]

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor I forgot to add the equations, could you check again?

Comment: Still correct! Those are the limits I inferred from your integrals and the sketch.

Comment: Everything else is correct but you should write integrand as $f(x,y)$ instead of $1$. So it should be $\displaystyle \int_0^3 \int_{y^2}^{(y^2+18)/3} f(x, y) \, dx \, dy$